# testimonial carousal not working in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, carousel, jquery-slider

i am working this [**sites**](http://testbytes.net/) testimonial section with a carousal slider.

The **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkpdpz4w/)**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.related_posts').bxSlider({
slideWidth: 350,
minSlides: 1,
maxSlides: 2,
slideMargin: 10
});
});  
</script>
```

**html:**

```
<ul class="related_posts wp_rp"><li><div class="message">

                We were able to go live with our product launch much before our estimated timeline and surprisingly without any bugs. We attribute this majorly to testbytes active involvement and efforts. Thanks Shaks. We’ll definitely recommend them to anyone.
            </div>

        <!-- CLIENT INFORMATION -->

        <div class="client">

            <div class="quote red-text">

                <i class="icon-fontawesome-webfont-294"></i>

            </div>

            <div class="client-info">

                <a class="client-name" target="_blank" href="http://www.flightspeak.net/">Leo Osahor</a>


                                    <div class="client-company">

                    Founder &amp; CEO
                </div>

            </div>


                      </div></li><li>
        <div class="message">

                testbytes knows its job very well. They helped me on few challenging projects and their attention to detail is remarkable. Another big asset is their flexibility that helped us meet our deadlines. testbytes follows stringent quality processes that ensures best quality software is delivered on time, highly professional team and I continue to come back to them always.
            </div><div class="client">

            <div class="quote red-text">

                <i class="icon-fontawesome-webfont-294"></i>

            </div>

            <div class="client-info">

                <a class="client-name" target="_blank" href="http://www.3rconnect.com">TajHaslani</a>


                                    <div class="client-company">

                    CEO
                </div>

            </div>
```

the slider works fine in desktop view .but when in try it in mobile it works in landscape mode but not in portrait.

[**landscape**](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http://testbytes.net&device=iphone-5&orientation=landscape)
**[portrait](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http://testbytes.net&device=android-nexus-4&orientation=portrait)**

please help where it went wrong.

Comment: i checked it .... it is working

Comment: the bullets are not working when we check in mobiles

Comment: (http://fiddle.jshell.net/qkpdpz4w/show/) open this slink and check in mobile view

Comment: but it is not working in testbytes.net

Comment: you are testing it in which browser?

Comment: i have checked the link you have posted on chrome  its working

Comment: lol .. i do not know what happened .. it just starterd working from some point